# Problems Parsing XML Output of CGI

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I have requested the data from our CGI in XML format.  I do this asynchronously and have a callback function like so:

```
var serverData;
function serverDataCallback(event) {
    if (event.target.readyState === 4) {
        if(event.target.status === 200) {
            var serverData = event.target.responseXML;
    }
}
```

If I `console.log` the event, I get an `XMLHttpRequestProgressEvent`.

The `target.responseXML` is exactly what I want, it looks like this in the Chrome debugging console of type `Document`:

```
<Params>
    <VCA>
        <Ch0>
            <enable>yes</enable>
        </Ch0>
    </VCA>
</Params>
```

However, I have no idea how to process this information!  I have had a look at lots of tutorials and the following does not work:

```
serverData.getElementByTagName('Ch0')[0].getElementByTagName('enable')[0]
```

There is just an exception saying that `getElementByTagName` does not exist.

If I `console.log` the `serverData` it is reported as a `Document`

I've never done an XML HTTP Request to return XML before, so don't really know what I'm doing!  Could anyone shed some light?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use the [DOM](http://www.w3.org/DOM/) (like you are in your example), you need to walk down the element tree just as elaborately as the XML document is. You also need to spell the functions correctly; it's called `getElementsByTagName` and not `getElementByTagName` since there's nothing unique about a tag name and thus the method will return an array of matching elements. A DOM solution would be something like this:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if ((this.readyState == 4) && (this.status == 200)) {
    var paramsElement = this.responseXML.getElementsByTagName('Params')[0];
    var vcaElement = paramsElement.getElementsByTagName('VCA')[0];
    var chElement = vcaElement.getElementsByTagName('Ch0')[0];
    var enableElement = chElement.getElementsByTagName('enable')[0];
    var enable = enableElement.data;

    console.debug(enable);
  }
};

xhr.open('GET', 'test.xml');
xhr.send();
```

There should of course be a lot of error checking here (each call to `getElementsByTagName` may return null), but it will hopefully get you started. I would, however, encourage you to not use the DOM or `XmlHttpRequest` directly, but instead an abstraction like [jQuery](http://jquery.org/):

```
$.get('test.xml', function(data, textStatus, xhr) {
  var $enable = $(data).find('Params VCA Ch0 enable');
  var enable = $enable.text();
  console.debug(enable);
}, 'xml');
```

As you can see, it's much less code and you get nice translation from the XML to a jQuery object that is a lot more powerful than DOM objects.

Comment: Thanks, I'm such an idiot for spelling the function wrong.  I'll have a look tomorrow at work.  I'm never sure about relying on jQuery as this needs to be a javascript namespace other people can use.  I'm not sure if I can force a dependency on jQuery with it.